# Xamarin intellisense bug

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, intellisense

I don't know, if StackOverflow is the right forum for my problem, but maybe someone can help me nevertheless.
When I open a *.axml* file with the **code editor instead the layout editor**, then the intellisense works fine, but as soon as I have reached four *views* in my layout, the intellisense stops working in the fifth *view*. So my questions are:

- Does this problem only happen for me,
- is it purposely caused by the starter version of Xamarin Studio,
- is it a general bug or
- something else?

If my English is terrible, feel free to correct me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow probably isn't the best place for this question.  Try posting at http://forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-studio as there's a much better chance of someone from Xamarin getting back to you there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having xaml intellisense problem and you are using Resharper;

> Disable ReSharper!

Visual Studio > Tools | Options | ReSharper | General : Suspend

**Update:**
*When I install the latest ReSharper version (2017.2), the problem is solved.*